# rm: cannot remove - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, root, rm

Anyone have any idea why I can't remove these?

```
~# find /var/lib/php5/ -xdev -depth -type f -size 0 -exec ls -al {} \; -exec lsattr {} \;  -exec rm -rf {} \;
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 23 05:20 /var/lib/php5/165498
-------------e-- /var/lib/php5/165498
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/php5/165498’: Permission denied
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 23 05:20 /var/lib/php5/217306
-------------e-- /var/lib/php5/217306
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/php5/217306’: Permission denied
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 23 05:20 /var/lib/php5/275922
-------------e-- /var/lib/php5/275922
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/php5/275922’: Permission denied
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 23 05:20 /var/lib/php5/148947
-------------e-- /var/lib/php5/148947
```

Seems like I should be able to?

```
~# whoami
root
```

fstab output

```
~# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
/dev/xvdb       /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2
```

namei output

```
~# namei -mo /var/lib/php5
f: /var/lib/php5
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
drwxr-xr-x root root php5
```

findmnt output

```
~# findmnt
TARGET                       SOURCE                             FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/                            /dev/disk/by-label/cloudimg-rootfs ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered
├─/sys                       sysfs                              sysfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                                              tmpfs      rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755
│ │ └─/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd systemd                            cgroup     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd
│ ├─/sys/fs/fuse/connections                                    fusectl    rw,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/debug                                           debugfs    rw,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security                                        securityfs rw,relatime
│ └─/sys/fs/pstore                                              pstore     rw,relatime
├─/proc                      proc                               proc       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/dev                       udev                               devtmpfs   rw,relatime,size=1908536k,nr_inodes=477134,mode=755
│ └─/dev/pts                 devpts                             devpts     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
├─/run                       tmpfs                              tmpfs      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=383888k,mode=755
│ ├─/run/lock                                                   tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k
│ ├─/run/shm                                                    tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
│ └─/run/user                                                   tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755
└─/mnt                       /dev/xvdb                          ext3       rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

mount output

```
~# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/dev/xvdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw,_netdev)
```

> >

EDIT: In repsonse to Dan Armstrong

selinux

```
~# ls -al /usr/sbin/getenforce
ls: cannot access /usr/sbin/getenforce: No such file or directory
```

apparmor

```
~# /usr/sbin/apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
4 profiles are loaded.
4 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
1 processes have profiles defined.
1 processes are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient (516)
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

os version

```
~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

stop apparmor

```
~# /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
 * Clearing AppArmor profiles cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [ OK ]
All profile caches have been cleared, but no profiles have been unloaded.
Unloading profiles will leave already running processes permanently
unconfined, which can lead to unexpected situations.

To set a process to complain mode, use the command line tool
'aa-complain'. To really tear down all profiles, run the init script
with the 'teardown' option."
```

retry rm

```
~# find /var/lib/php5/ -xdev -depth -type f -size 0 -exec ls -al {} \; -exec lsattr {} \;  -exec rm -rf {} \;
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 23 05:20 /var/lib/php5/165498
-------------e-- /var/lib/php5/165498
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/php5/165498’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything in what you posted that points to the cause.  It does, however, rule out the most obvious causes.

It may be worth looking into SELinux.

Run the following to check current level of enforcement:

```
/usr/sbin/getenforce
```

If it says "Enforcing", this could possibly be part of the equation.  Then try temporarily disabling SELinux with:

```
/usr/sbin/setenforce 0
```

Any difference?

Comment: Replied in an edit as it was too big for a comment. Thanks for the tip, however it doesn't seem to be AppArmor - it is Ubuntu, but I checked for SELinux anyway.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Check the permissions and the attributes on the /var/lib/php5 itself:
`ls -ld /var/lib/php5 ; lsattr -d /var/lib/php5`
If you cannot modify the directory, you cannot delete its contents.

Comment: Bingo!

Something seems to be adding +i to the directory.

Comment: Just to get rid of some files, and free up inodes, I have added -exec chattr -i /var/lib/php5 to my find command.

I guess I will have to check crons and other places to see what keeps changing the attributes on the folder?